# Проблема с удалением элемента списка методом remove(), в цикле python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
l_o_v = [(years,yrs), (days,dys), (hours,hrs), (minutes,mnts), (seconds,sec)]    #LIST OF VALUES
for each in l_o_v:
    if each[0] == 0:
        l_o_v.remove(each)   #IF each[0] == 0 then we delete
        print(l_o_v)
print(l_o_v)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Предполагается, что при нулевом значении из списка удаляется элемент-кортеж
Но почему-то это срабатывает только 1 раз, думаю, что это из-за метода remove, потому-что он удаляет первый элемент, но для его повторения я загнал его в цикл.
Можно ли как-то заменить REMOVE? 
Мне нужно конкретно удалить, а не заменить элемент, потому-что дальше условие, в котором используется длина списка.

Ожидаю [(10,'seconds')] вместо получаемого результата.

Comment: Нельзя делать итерации по списку и изменять его. Это чревато разными неожиданными результатами. Создавайте новый список и сохраняйте туда результат.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Как вариант, можно сформировать новый список по условию

- Через генерацию списка:

  ```
  l_o_v = [each for each in l_o_v if each[0] != 0]
  print(l_o_v)
  ```
- Через функциональный стиль:

  ```
  l_o_v = list(filter(lambda each: each[0] != 0, l_o_v))
  print(l_o_v)
  ```

Answer (score 7):

Так делать нельзя! После того как удален первый (т.е. нулевой) элемент, следующий элемент в цикле будет не второй, а третий, т.к. все элементы сдвинулись на один к началу, а цикл работает с номерами элементов (удалили первый, второй стал первым, и в цикл он уде не попадет, т.к. теперь на очереди второй, а это бывший третий).  Вы можете добавить вместо пустых строк какие-нибудь значения и увидите, что в итоговом списке идут элементы из исходного через один.

Вместо этого нужно создать новый список и добавлять туда элементы:

```
res = []
for each in l_o_v:
    if each[0] != 0:
        res.append(each)
        print(res)
print(res)
```

Comment: А итерировать поэлементно и задом наперед, в Питоне так нельзя?

Comment: @KromstersayssupportMonica можно

Answer (score 2):

на самом деле варианта два

1) создать новый список, как описано в других ответах

2) итерироватся по копии списка

```
for each in list(l_o_v):
    if each[0] == 0:
        l_o_v.remove(each)   #IF each[0] == 0 then we delete

# или        
for each in l_o_v.copy():
    if each[0] == 0:
        l_o_v.remove(each)   #IF each[0] == 0 then we delete
```

Answer (score 0):

Нужно перевернуть список.если работать с копией то если одинаковый элемент то удалится первый попавший.

```
for each in l_o_v[::-1]:#либо reversed(l_o_v)
    if each[0] == 12:
       l_o_v.remove(each)  # IF each[0] == 0 then we delete
       print(l_o_v)
print(l_o_v)
```