# Не работает код. Ошибка IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x

Не работает код. Ошибка IndexError: list index out of range

```
i = 0
s = 0
n, k = input().split()
n, k = int(n), int(k)
a = input().split()
a = [int(item) for item in a]

while s != n: 
    if a[i] < k:
        del a[i-1]  

                     
    i += 1
    s += 1
print(len(a))
```

Comment: Добавьте к вопросу входные данные и ожидаемый результат, а то непонятно ничего

Comment: Должен вводить:7 4 потом 7 1 4 7 6 3 4 должно виводить 3

Comment: Программа должна выводить длину самой длинной последовательности чисел в списке крупнее за переменную k

Comment: а можно еще раз и по-русски, что именно должна делать программа - а то ` длину самой длинной последовательности чисел в списке крупнее за переменную k` звучит не очень и не сказано для чего тогда вам параметр `n` еще

Comment: @Zhihar упрощу, ему нужно отсечь числа из списка которые не подходят под условие. какое условие в данном случае неважно

Comment: если условие касается независимо каждого элемента, то `filter` наше все - но там же вопрос вроде про максимальную последовательность, а тут уже так просто не получится

Comment: @Zhihar   Например, если ввести 6 5 отделал во второй строке должно быть 6 цифр
и некоторые из них должны быть больше чем  5. Задача ищет сколько цифр подряд крупнее 5 например.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Проблема с удалением элемента списка методом remove(), в цикле python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1032299/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bc-remove-%d0%b2-%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b5-python)

Answer (score 1):

Вы изменяете существующий список. Таким образом, когда вы удалили некоторые числа из списка, цикл считает что список еще не закончился, т.к. он вычисляет по ИЗНАЧАЛЬНОЙ длине списка, которая не изменяется.

Вам нужно создать отдельный список и помещать туда все числа, которые вам нужны.

Answer (score 1):

```
if a[i] < k:
    del a[i-1]
```

вы идете вперед по массиву и удаляете элементы массива уже за собой

массив при этом уменьшается и его размер постепенно уменьшается

естественно, что рано или поздно вы просто выходите за пределы массива

Опишите, что конкретно вы хотели своим кодом сделать то? скорее всего решение будет использовать совершенно другие принципы

**P.S.**

код

```
n, k = input().split()
n, k = int(n), int(k)
```

удобно заменить на такой:

```
n, k = map(int, input().split())
```

код

```
a = input().split()
a = [int(item) for item in a]
```

удобно заменить на

```
a = list(map(int, input().split()))
```

Comment: Программа должна выводить длину самой длинной последовательности чисел в списке  крупнее за переменную k

Comment: что значит `крупнее за переменную k` и что тогда в вашем случае параметр `n`?

Comment: n по сути бескорыстная я ее сделай только для того чтобы показать сколько цифр в списке и в условии задачи так было написано. Например, если ввести 6 5 то во второй строке должно быть 6 цифр
и некоторые из них должны быть крупнее 5. Задача ищет сколько цифр подряд крупнее 5 например.

Answer (score 1):

> Задача ищет сколько цифр подряд крупнее 5 например. – d4riy 1 минуту
> назад

Ну с этим описанием уже можно работать:

Решение в лоб:

```
# получить данные
n, k = map(int, input().split())

arr = list(map(int, input().split()))

# найти длину требуемой последовательности
max_len = 0
current_len = 0

for num in arr:
    if num > k:
        current_len += 1
    else:
        if current_len > max_len:
            max_len = current_len
        current_len = 0

# учесть, что максимальная последовательность может не прерываться
if current_len > max_len:
    max_len = current_len

# вывести результат
print(max_len)
```

Можно чуть уменьшить кол-во проверок:

```
# найти длину требуемой последовательности
max_len = 0
current_len = 0

for num in arr:
    if num > k:
        current_len += 1
        max_len = current_len if current_len > max_len else max_len
    else:
        current_len = 0
```

Ну и наверное самый короткий код, но для извращенцев:

```
# найти длину требуемой последовательности
m, c = 0, 0

for num in arr:
    c, m = (c + 1, c + 1 if c + 1 > m else m) if num > k else (0, m)
```

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное!

Answer (score 0):

```
while s != n: 
    if a[i] < k:
        del a[i-1]  
    i += 1
    s += 1
```

Что касается общей логики работы вашей программы, не могу ничего сказать, потому что так её и не понял. Но вот конкретно в этом куске у вас точно ошибка, потому что вы периодически уменьшаете список `a` на `1` элемент, а индекс `i` у вас всё-равно проходит значения от `1` до `n-1`, как будто со списком `a` ничего не происходит. Вероятно, `i` нужно увеличивать на `1` только в ветке `else:` которую нужно добавить:

```
if a[i] < k:
    del a[i-1] 
else: 
    i += 1
```