# Как вывести по одному элементу из списка?

Tags: python-3.x, циклы

Задача: Создайте программу, которая будет выводить список слов в случайном порядке. На экране должны печататься без повторений все слова из представленного списка.

В интернете нашел некоторые способы, но я хочу понять, почему такой код не работает.
На первый взгляд, все должно работать, но, очевидно, я что-то упусукаю).
Впервые тут, извините, если что-то не так)

```
import random

a = [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

while a:
    num = random.choice(a)
    for i in a:
        if i == num:
            a.remove(i)

    print(num)
```

Comment: Так какой вывод считается правильным для приведённого примера  с несколькими единицами?

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, к примеру, '1, 2, 3, 4, 5'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваш код легко починить, достаточно итерироваться по копии списка:

```
for i in a.copy():
          ^^^^^^^
```

Проблема в том, что когда вы удаляете элементы из списка, по которому итерируетесь, то процесс итерирования сбивается и пропускает элементы из-за того, что изменилась "на ходу" длина списка.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, а почему так происходит процесс итерирования сбивается? Это просто из-за особенности языка? Спасибо еще раз

Comment: @NewBee  это особенности процесса.https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1032304/282277

Answer (score 2):

Обратите внимание на ваше условие: "На экране должны печататься без повторений все слова из представленного списка."
Это можно решить через преобразование листа в множество. Множество в python - "контейнер", содержащий не повторяющиеся элементы в случайном порядке.

```
a = [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = set(a)
for x in b:
    print(x)
```

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых, для исключения дубликатов нужно сделать то, что @A_Vaclav со множеством посоветовал.

Во-вторых, для вывода очищенного списка в случайном порядке его можно перемешать с помощью функции shuffle

```
import random
a = [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
a = list(set(a))
print(a)


random.shuffle(a)
for x in a:
    print(x)
```

А можно и вручную выполнить перемешивание Фишера-Йетса. Заметьте, что выбранный элемент ставится в конец (в текущую конечную позицию), и при желании его можно удалять из списка.

```
n = len(a)
for i in range(n):
    id = random.randint(0, n - i - 1)
    a[n - i - 1], a[id] = a[id], a[n - i - 1]
    print(a[n - i - 1])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

a = [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

while a:
    num = random.choice(a)
    while num in a:
        a.remove(num)
    print(num, end=" ")
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]